# How can I submit data from 2 php files to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I am trying to combine data from p1.php with data from p2.php and submit together to mySQL, **in p1.php**:

```
$.post("p2.php", $("#myForm1").serialize());
```

and then direct to p2.php :

```
location.href='p2.php';
```

In **p2.php** I also have a form IDed myForm2:

```
$.post("p2.php", $("#myForm2").serialize());
```

then in p2.php, I inset data to mySQL, but the result is I can't really have the data from myForm1 (which was located in p1.php),

What should I do with it??? THX!

Answer (score 2):

Save the data in the session array.

Comment: I understand your point of view @DannyBeckett, but I am not going to modify my answer.
I don't like to read lengthy answers so I write the way I like to read - short (unless there are no other way, obviously).
I thank you for bother to explain. I would suggest you to up vote one of the other (lengthy) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Get the serialized data from myFOrm1, and put it into hidden field in myForm2, then when submitting myForm2 you will get everything from that form + the data from the first form. 
You can set the serialized data from myForm1 into $_SESSION or smth, so it will not be accessible from the frontend. Then, at any moment you can retrieve that data.

Comment: Hi, I am new to php, could you please explain how to serialize data from myFOrm1, and put it into hidden field? I tried serialized data from myForm1 into $_SESSION but it doesn't work. Thanks!